# Flutter событие прокрутки для FutureBuilder и ListView по достижении 80% длины экрана?

Tags: listview, flutter, dart

У меня REST приложение которое берет с сайта постранично информацию и конвертирует в ListView список. Событие когда необходимо получить новую порцию данных срабатывает по достижении конца прокрути и выглядит так

```
_controller.addListener(() {

   //При достижении конца прокрутки
    if (_controller.position.atEdge) {

        //Запрашиваю новую порцию  данных
    }
});
```

Мне хотелось, что бы данные запрашивались не в самам конце экрана, а немного раньше, что-бы пользователь не ждал загрузки новой порции данных и они подкачивались в фоне. Для этого я пробовал такой вариант

```
 _controller.addListener(() {

    //Сравниваю текущую позицию скролинга списка с максимальной минус какоё-то значение, что-бы  срабатывало заранее
    if (_controller.position.pixels >=  _controller.position.maxScrollExtent-200) {
     
       //Запрашиваю новую порцию  данных

     }
 });
```

То есть определял текущую позицию скролинга и сравнивал с максимальной, но немного раньше, на 200 пикселей. Этот вариант не рабоатет, потому-что функция которая возвращает JSON данные работает асинхронно, а событие срабатывает множество раз и получатеся за несколько секунд 10-15 запросов, которые отрабатывает в случайном, а не строгом порядке и данные получаются вперемешку из-за этого

Пробовал вариант `_controller.position.pixels ==  _controller.position.maxScrollExtent-200` но он совсем не работает, потому-что скролинг текущей позиции очень точный и попасть в это значение просто невозможно, событие совсем не отрабатывает. Существут ли способ, что бы можно было событие срабатывало один раз на каком-то участке списка немного заранее, до его завершения, этакий lazy loading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Должно работать как вам нужно (возможно придется доработать, когда данные загрузятся. Таймер нужно будет поставить наверное):

```
bool isLoading = false;

...

_controller.addListener(() async {
  if (!isLoading && (_controller.position.pixels >= _controller.position.maxScrollExtent - 200)) {
    isLoading = true;
    await loadData().then((_) => isLoading = false); // или .whenComplete((_) => isLoading = false);
  }
});
```

Comment: Там вся прелесть в том, что событие срабатывает 10-15 раз и даже если  loadData() обернуть синглтоном, то await непонятно когда результат вернет.

Comment: @АлександрИнженер isLoading  не даст запустить другие запросы пока самый первый не выполниться. Попробуйте.

Comment: Спасибо! Не увидел параметр, всё работает!